which feature in xfce4 enables wifi connexions?
In my last Debian install (bookworm, xfce), I had a feature in the panel when I used to click, the list of available wifi access points was listed, enabling to choose one and input the password for the first connexion. Then later, the connexion was automatic.
I have reinstalled Debian and cannot find how to setup this again. Could someone guide me please?
At present time, I get only a network-manager window, without discovery of available wifi access points, only the ones I have input, and it is not friendly.

The menu, in X11 desktop environments such as Xfce, is usually provided by nm-applet (which is packaged as 'network-manager-applet' in Debian).

This is actually "Applet NetworkManager". I cannot figure out how I have installed it, probably it comes with NetWorkManager, but there is no package 'network-manager-applet' in Debian. Eventually, it works: it lists available WLANs.
